# Ignore JSON fields from ResponseEntity<> inside @Controller

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Suppose that I have this 2 entities:

**Area.class:**

```
class Area {
    String areaName;
    List<Customer> customers;
}
```

**Customer.class:**

```
class Customer {
   String customerName;
   Area area;
}
```

And in my @Controller I Have a @GetMapping mapped to get some **Area** that will return a ResponseEntity, as a JSON, and it return this:

```
{"areaName":"Area Z", customers:[{"customerName":"John", "area": {"areaName":"Area Z", customers:[{"customerName":"John", "area": ... }]}}]}
```

So is basically an infinity loop, how do I **ignore the area field** and just return this:

```
{"areaName":"Area Z", customers:[{"customerName":"John"}, {"customerName":"Zack"}]}
```

**Please remember that I want to ignore it in the @ControllerClass, and not putting @JSONIgnore in the Customer.class, because I want to do it again returning the Customer with the Area.areaName**

Thank you for any help!

*Ps: I found something about JsonView but I don't know how to use it*

Answer (score 1):

One way is using [@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)](http://baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) which eliminates the null fields so in the controller eliminates `Area area` in `Customer` class by setting it to null

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Customer {
    String customerName;
    Area area;
 }
```

In controller before returning response just set the `area` to null

```
area.getCustomers().forEach(cust->cust.setArea(null));
```